# Understanding Expression Tree and Parameter Evaluation

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm attempting to modify an expression tree that dynamically builds a Contains expression that ultimately results in SQL like

`P IN (123, 124, 125, 200, 201)`

to instead check perform range checks, which ultimately results in SQL like

`(P >= 123 AND P <= 125) OR (P >= 200 AND P <= 201)`

I'm basing my solution on [this post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t645784-linq-where-clause.html).

```
static public Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> 
BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    // Removed for post: Input checks and edge cases

    var equals = 
      values.Select(value => 
       (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, 
                                    Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => 
                                             Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

I'm able to get the range checking to work if I provide the value for comparison:

```
long testValue = 5;
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> ranges = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>() 
{
    new KeyValuePair<long, long>(3, 6),
    new KeyValuePair<long, long>(10, 12),
    new KeyValuePair<long, long>(20, 20),
};

List<BinaryExpression> rangeExpressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();

foreach (var pair in ranges)
{
    var greaterThanOrEqual = 
        Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Constant(testValue), 
                                      Expression.Constant(pair.Key));

    var lessThanOrEqual = 
        Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression.Constant(testValue), 
                                   Expression.Constant(pair.Value));

    var inRange = Expression.AndAlso(greaterThanOrEqual, lessThanOrEqual);
    rangeExpressions.Add(inRange);
}

var final = 
    rangeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression>((a, b) => Expression.Or(a, b));

var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(final).Compile()();
```

However, I cannot sort out how to get the value for comparison from the passed-in expression when I drop that code into the method to be used with Linq.  The signature of that method is:

```
Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> 
BuildRangeExpression<TElement>(
    Expression<Func<TElement, long>> valueSelector, 
    IEnumerable<long> values)
```

and it is used like:

```
Expression<MyType, bool> match = 
    BuildRangeExpression<MyType, long>(my => my.ProductCode, productCodes);

var result = db.MyTypes.Where(match);
```

**QUESTION**

How can I evaluate

```
Expression<Func<TElement, long>> valueSelector
```

so that I can use the value passed into `BuildRangeExpression` instead of my currently hard-coded value

```
long testValue = 5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code from the blog post has exactly what you need: all you have to do is to use `valueSelector.Body` instead of your `Expression.Constant()` and also add the original parameter to the generated expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>
    BuildRangeExpression<TElement, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector,
    IEnumerable<Tuple<TValue, TValue>> values)
{
    var p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

    var equals = values.Select(
        tuple =>
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(tuple.Item1)),
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(tuple.Item2))));

    var body = equals.Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Expression.Parameter`.

Create a parameter:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TElement), "arg")
```

Instead of `Expression.Constant(testvalue)`, you will need to put `param`.

Then, you need to do:

```
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(final, param).Compile()
```

Comment: This is not enough, the expression should also access the property from `valueSelector`.