# Select with Many Discrete Values Possible in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Article](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nchar](10) NOT NULL)
```

users are allowed to select one or more categories for which they would like to view data.  Typically they will select 1-20 categories.  To accommodate that, I generate parameterized queries similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM Article
WHERE CategoryId IN (@c1, @c2, @c3, @c4, @c5)
```

However, in some rare use cases a user can legitimately select hundreds of categories.  This lead me to discover a limitation of Linq-to-Entities, which I worked around by forming [ranges of category codes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14945983/141172).  Unfortunately this only pushes off the issue, as there are limits to the size of a query that can be passed to SQL Server.

I would like to refactor this query to avoid any hard limits.  My first thought was to create a temporary table containing the requested categories, and performing an inner join against that temporary table in lieu of the `IN(...)` clause.  However, I understand that temporary tables can be quite slow.

Is there a more elegant and/or better performing solution to this problem?

Comment: If you are creating a temporary table with the values, I would deal with this as follows: `select * from article where categoryId in (select categoryId from tempTable)`

Comment: There are some religious wars on "IN" vs "Where Exists".  I default to "Where Exists"......but you can test each scenario.  Sometimes there is some "it doesn't matter" thoughts out there...but I find it better to test.

Comment: @granadaCoder: In my case WHERE EXISTS is much faster (despite blog posts claiming the optimizer will sort that out).  However, that's not the crux of the issue.  The real problem here is handing N parameters efficiently, where N can be large.

Comment: That's been my experience (that where exists is faster).  But I had a manager tell me once that it "didn't matter" because he read it on a blog, some where some time.  I guess my final advice might be.....you do things up until they make sense.....so maybe you gotta not go Linq-To-Whatever here, and go back to ADO.NET for this specific need.  Maybe somebody will come up with something else.

Comment: @granadaCoder I once spent a month with my team in the lovely Germany city of Wuertzburg doing a special project because my manager played a round of golf with somebody who had a "good idea" :-)  Fun project, but the tee talk was about as authoritative as the blog your manager read.  You're advice is sound... when you identify a performance issue, benchmark alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first instinct is correct, thopugh you might find a table-valued variable sufficient in place of a temp table. Don't worry about the performance in a case like this; it won't be significant. An index could always be created onthe temp table if needed, but that seems unlikley. Is there an index on the CategoryId field?

Comment: If temp tables actually are slow, they may be located on the wrong physical drive. They should be on a faster drive, because they are so useful in making other queries run efficiently, but perhaps your Sysdmin has not thought of this.

Comment: I'm referring to articles like http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2002/derived-temp-tables/ rather than any specific performance measurement in my environment.

Comment: Many of the commentators on that article quote personal experience that supports my proposal. I have specializaed in programming and tuning SQL Server databases for over 20 years. Don't be fooled by my low  (current) reputation - I was at 7 a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Oops.  I missed the Linq part.

Here is a alternate syntax that may be worth a try (for performance reasons, not for string length reasons)

```
Select * from dbo.Article art where exists ( select null from ( select 0 as MyV union all select 2 as MyV union all select 3 as MyV ) as derived1 where derived1.MyV = art.CategoryId )
```

......................

This is how I handle it.

Sometimes my variable table is changed to a #temp table.  I test the 2 different scenarios for performance.

You can pass as many or as few values via xml.

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<root>
  <category myvalue="1" />
  <category myvalue="2" />
  <category myvalue="3" />
</root>'



declare @holder table ( CatID int )
Insert into @holder (CatID)
SELECT
    myvalue = MyXmlTable.value('(@myvalue)', 'int')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/root/category') AS Tbl(MyXmlTable)


select * from @holder    

SELECT * FROM Article art
where exists (select null from @holder hold where hold.CatID = art.CategoryId
```

Bigger write up here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stored+Procedures/thezerotonparameterproblem/2283/

Comment: In this instance I'm using ADO.Net rather than Linq, though the Linq issue I reference is for a related query in the same app.  Can you help me understand the `select null` part of the Linq option?  I presume this Linq form would ultimately be translated into a SQL command that suffers from the same maximum command length if there were many parameter values selected?

Comment: the 'null' is just there because you need something. yo could put "select 1" or "select hold.CatId" or whatever....the bigger thing is the WHERE EXISTS (instead of the 'IN') clause.  Yeah, you'll still have the max length issue.....So... I don't know. I was trying to provide a different option and something to think about.  I think you're between a rock and hard place.  Passing down a bunch of values so they can be inserted into a #temp table for later joining to...can work, but seems like alot of overhead.  So bottom line, my idea may just be off base.  But that's how I handle the 0:N problem